# jQuery animate function - hide and stretch divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a page with divs as;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="switch"></div>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="viewer"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

id `switch` is a trigger, which is meant to toggle animation. On 1st click, it should shrink the width of `sidebar` to 5px and width of `list` to 0px, and the margin-left of `switch` to 5px and the left of `viewer` to 5px. When user again click the trigger, everything may return to previous state and positions. In short i want to toggle hide/show sidebar. The animations should be some sliding effect towards left and then towards right.

You can have a look at what I am talking about [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/EzAV2/) and an updated fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EzAV2/7/).

Comment: In your jsfiddle code you only move the `#viewer`. Why? If you want to move 4 things do 4 animations. `$('#viewer').animate({left: 0});$('#sidebar').animate({"width": 5});...`

Comment: hi @SPL_Splinter, i made some corrections and made a new fiddle.. but div `switch` got a bug.. Have a look @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your updated code, you are setting the "left" of the #switch when you gave it a margin of 200px;

change,

```
$('#switch').animate({"left": 5});
$('#switch').animate({"left": 200});
```

to,

```
$('#switch').animate({"margin-left": 5});
$('#switch').animate({"margin-left": 200});
```

Comment: i updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/EzAV2/9/   but the switch disappear at the beginning and reappear at the end of animation. got a fix??

Comment: @blasteralfred Just ignore the side bar, [http://jsfiddle.net/EzAV2/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/EzAV2/11/), I removed its styling and anim. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yea i mean it buddy.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine, it is just your css that needs the fine tuning.

```
#switch {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: #CC0066;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

See the codes here: http://jsfiddle.net/EzAV2/8/

Comment: `position:relative;` is a nice touch

Comment: yea i got it. but switch disappears @ beginning and reappears at the end of animation. Why is this happening??