# toggle width resize animation - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have `<div id="test"></div>`and `<a id="trigger"></a>`. Div has width 300px. I want the div to re size it's width to 100px when user click trigger and want to re size to previous size when user again click the trigger. How can i make this using jquery??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: you already posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583909/jquery-animate-function-hide-and-stretch-divs

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assign a variable of 1 for click and 0 for unclick and then use the .click function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  TriggerClick = 0;

  $("a#trigger").click(function(){
    if(TriggerClick==0){
         TriggerClick=1;
         $("div#test").animate({width:'100px'}, 500);
    }else{
         TriggerClick=0;
         $("div#test").animate({width:'300px'}, 500);
    };
  });
});
```

**UPDATE - BETTER ANSWER**

I made this suggestion awhile back; but believe there is a more elegant and pragmatic approach to solving this.  You could use CSS transitions and have jquery simply add/remove a class that initiates the transition:

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2q0odoLk/

CSS:

```
#test {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;

  /* setup the css transitions */
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  -moz-transition: width 1s;
  transition: width 1s;
}

#test.small {
   width: 100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("a#trigger").on('click', function(){
    $("div#test").toggleClass('small');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is `Html Part` of this toggle:

```
<div id="start">
    <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

This is `CSS part` for that:

```
<style>
    #start{ margin-bottom:60px; display:block; font-size:16px; width:14px; height:79px; position:relative; top:25px; line-height:21px; color:#F0F; background:url(./start1.JPG) left top no-repeat;}    
    .slide{ background:#98bf21; max-width:500px; width:100; height:100px;position:absolute; left:14px;}
</style>
     <script> 
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            function tog()
            {  
                var w = $(".slide").css('width');

                 if(w=='0px')
                 {
                    $(".slide").animate({
                    width:500
                 });
           }
           else
           {
              $(".slide").animate({
              width:0
              });
           }
        }

        $("#start").click(function()
        {
            tog();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an .click()-Event to #trigger and toggle the animation.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should to the trick.

```
$('#trigger').bind('click', function() { $('#test').animate({"width": "100px"}, "slow"); })
```

Comment: that solution only works for the 1st click, then all other clicks after that will result in nothing visibly happening.  Also, I like a little more control over my speed of the animate function usually so I tend to specify an actual milliseconds rather than slow,medium, or fast.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a shorter but yet working version you could do this:

```
$('a#trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var w = ($('div#test').width() == 300 ? 100 : 300);
    $('div#test').animate({width:w},150);
});
```

The shortest version:

```
$('a#trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#test').animate({width:($('div#test').width() == 300 ? 100 : 300)},150);
});
```

On a function:

```
function toggleWidth(target, start, end, duration) {
    var w = ($(target).width() == start ? end : start);
    $(target).animate({width:w},duration);
    return w;
}
```

Usage:

```
$('a#trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleWidth($("div#test"), 300, 100, 150);
});
```

Finally on a JQuery.fn.extend function:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleWidth: function(start, end, duration) {
        var w = ($(this).width() == start ? end : start);
        $(this).animate({width:w},duration);
        return w;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
$('a#trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div#test").toggleWidth(300, 100, 150);
});
```